# Comparison not working?

Tags: assembly, nasm

This is the nasm code I use to loop, label for is a couple of rows above, but when running I get an infinite loop. Replacing [n] with an actual number it works fine.

```
;read [n] above and set [i] to zero   
for:
mov rax, 0
;i++
mov rcx, [i]
add rcx, 1
mov [i], rcx

mov rdi, outformat
mov rsi, [i]
mov rdx, [n]
call printf

mov eax, [i]
cmp eax, [n]
jl for
ret
```

This piece of code prints that only the [i] is incrementing and n does not change. Example output is:

> 2532/3

when I input 3 as [n] and let [i] increase by 1 in every iteration. How can I fix this to also work with [n]?

Comment: You have to post more of your code to make any sense.

Comment: @user3144770 updated the entire loop

Comment: **How can I fix this to also work with [n]?** It already uses [n]! You explicitly make an input into [n] (**;read [n] above**) and use it several times in the code.

Comment: yes, but this code produces an endless loop, while the value of n is also written and correct...

Comment: There's not much to go on! The use of EAX doesn't seem to logic. Did you try changing EAX to RAX ? An endless loop might actually be a long running loop.

Comment: I have tried changing the EAX to many others, RAX, EDX, ECX, RDX, RCX and none of them worked. The loop doesn't end even with [n] set to 3.